# Other methods to derive index values from an array

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Given an example NumPy array *a* such as

```
array([[1, A, 3.00, 4, 5],
       [2, B, 4.00, 5, 6],
       [3, C, 5.00, 6, 7],
       [3, D, 6.00, 7, 8],
       [3, E, 7.00, 8, 9]])
```

my goal is to find the indices where the value 3 occurs in the first column, and select the very last index value.

I can think of two different methods of collecting the index values in a list.

SOLUTION 1: Use a for loop

```
indx = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if int(a[i,0]) == int(3):
        indx.append(i)
indx = indx[-1]
```

SOLUTION 2: Use NumPy *where*

```
indx = np.where(a[:,0] == 3)
indx = indx[0]
indx = indx[-1]
```

However, I have a tendency to find better methods to solving problems, and that actually helps me learn more. Given such a problem, does anyone know of any other solution that I am not aware of? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 reasons why your solutions are inefficient for your task:

1. Using your `for` loop, you search from first to last, instead of last to
   first. In addition, you are unnecessarily building a list.
2. For `numpy.where`, you retrieve *all* the indices, before you select the final one.

You can resolve these 2 issues via a custom function which searches from last to first. In addition, you can improve performance via JIT-compiling.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, 100000)

@jit(nopython=True)
def indexer(arr, item):
    for idx, val in enumerate(arr[::-1]):
        if val == item:
            return len(arr) - idx - 1

%timeit indexer(arr, 5)          # 2.52 µs
%timeit np.where(arr==5)[0][-1]  # 454 µs
```

Comment: What does the *@jit (nopython = True)* mean?

Comment: Look up numba, it's a way to compile bits of numpy code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a simpler built-in that I have not considered, the simplest method would be to reverse the first layer of the array and search for the first occurrence.

```
reversed_a = a[::-1]
for i, item in enumerate(reversed_a ):
    if int(item[0]) == 3:
        break
indx = len(a) - i  - 1
```